# Implementing a TTS service for Windows 10

Tags: windows, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis, microsoft-speech-api

I'm working on a research project in which we create a new text-to-speech (TTS) engine, that converts text to spoken audio.
As the engine is already performing good, we try to make it usable by a large number of applications which made us want the engine to show up as a TTS voice on Windows 10.

In Microsoft's developer documentations, all I found was information on how I can use exisiting/already installed voices in my application. However, I didn't find any information on how to implement a voice so that it shows up as a Windows voice and can be used by any application using the Speech SDK or SAPI.

Which interface do I have to implement or what API do I have to connect to in order to get our new TTS engine work with Windows Speech?

I already crawled the documentation of the Microsoft Speech SDK as well as developer sites like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.synthesis.ttsengine

Answer (score 2):

You should look at the [TTS Engine Vendor Porting Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms717037(v=vs.85)).   You need to implement  [`ISpTTSEngine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms719558%28v%3Dvs.85%29), which does all the work, and [`ISpObjectWithToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms718356%28v%3Dvs.85%29), which manages registration and creation.

Comment: Why isn't this marked as the answer? Seems like the answer, and if the linked page is not omitting something, the ISpTTSEngine interface seems a lot simpler than I had expected. It only has two methods to implement.

Comment: Yeah, implementing a TTS engine is straightforward.  (Way, way, way easier than implementing an SR engine.). That being said, Microsoft isn’t making further investments into SAPI.